# What should std::vector::data() return if the vector is empty?

Tags: c++, vector

According to the draft standard ([23.3.6.4 vector data](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)), data() points to the underlying array and `[data(), data() + size())` must be a valid range:

```
T* data() noexcept;
const T* data() const noexcept;

    1 Returns: A pointer such that [data(),data() + size()) is a valid range. For a non-empty vector,
data() == &front().
    2 Complexity: Constant time
```

But what if the vector is empty? When I construct a zero-size vector:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const int NUM = 0*10;
    std::vector< double > v( NUM, 0.0 );
    std::cerr << "V : "<< v.data() << std::endl;
}
```

MSVC 2010 returns null, but on Linux (with GCC 4.2.1 and Intel 12.1) I get a non-null address.

Is `vector::data()` allowed to or should it return null? Could an implementation, for example, do a default-size initial allocation and return a (non-null) pointer to it?

**Edit:** Several answers focus on the validity of an empty-range. I fully agree there.

I would really like to see a good reference or explanation for: Is it *allowed to*, *must it* return null or *may it* also return non-null?

Comment: The range is `[data(), data()+size())`; `[null, null)` is a valid empty range. Also, more recent GCC versions [also returns a null pointer](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0825deec6cc66b3d).

Comment: @T.C. I agree, but is [same random address, same random address] also a valid range and may vector::data() return it?

Comment: Note that the range is half-open. If that "random address" is valid, then `[random address, same random address)` is a valid empty range.

Comment: @T.C in your example, if you call `vector::reserve(20)` before calling `data()`, your pointer is non-null, while size is still 0.

Comment: Re. your edit, there is nothing that says it should return `nullptr`. It must return a valid range, so it *can* return `nullptr`, but doesn't have to.

Comment: @juanchopanza. You are right, my edit was a bit unclear. I clarified that I would like to see a reference or explanation if non-null is allowed. Thanks.

Comment: The quote is in @massimiliano's answer.

Comment: With respect to your edit, which kind of reference are you looking for that is more compelling than the standard?

Comment: @Massimiliano. I was hoping for something more than the valid empty range... M.M. gives a good explanation that it is unspecified, hence "anything is allowed". Maybe I should upvote his answer and accept yours.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The convention for ranges is `[inclusive, exclusive)`, that is if you iterate over a range `[X,Y)` you will conceptually do the following (pseudo-code):

```
for( iterator ii = X; ii != Y; ++ii) {
...
}
```

This permits to express an empty range as `[X,X)`. Also this empty range is perfectly well defined for **each address**, no matter if it is valid or invalid.

That said the requirements for `data()` are **(emphasis mine)**:

> **23.3.6.4**  **[vector.data]**
>
> T* data() noexcept;
>
> const T* data() const noexcept;
>
> Returns: A pointer such that **[data(),data() + size()) is a valid range**. For a
>   non-empty vector, data() == &front().

It seems to me that the only unconditional guarantee is that `[data(),data() + size())` should be a valid range. For `size() == 0` the member function `data()` may return any value and the range will be a valid empty range. Therefore I would say that *an implementation is allowed to return a non-null pointer if `size()` is zero*.

Comment: I don't think the empty range `[X,X)` can be called valid for any `X` in C++. The only thing you can legally do to a pointer variable that contains an invalid address other than NULL is to overwrite it. Even just comparing the variable to some other variable or literal yields UB. If the address is valid though, having a `T*` pointing there should be fine, even if no `T` exists at that address. This is how `vector` is able to legally return a non-null value for an empty vector: the address _is_ valid - it just points to "raw" memory instead of a `T`.

Answer (score 7):

None of the wording in the standard suggests a given value for data() if the vector is empty().

And here's some definitive proof of why you should not assume it might be zero, even though it sometimes is:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>


void value_of_data(std::vector<int> const& v)
{
    std::cout << "empty() = " << v.empty() << ", " << "data() = " << static_cast<const void*>(v.data()) << std::endl;
}



int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    value_of_data(v);

    v.resize(100, 0);
    v.clear();
    value_of_data(v);
}
```

example output (gcc7.2, -O2, linux):

```
empty() = 1, data() = 0
empty() = 1, data() = 0x7ebc30
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd1d13200c8b9a3a

Comment: I agree that I should not assume that it is null, note that I also showed a similar situation in my question (simply construct a zero-sized vector). But I was more asking for a "definitive" reference to the standard.

Answer (score 2):

There is a state that an object can be valid but unspecified:

> **valid but unspecified state** [§ 17.3]
>
> an object state that is not specified except that the object’s
>   invariants are met and operations on the object behave as specified
>   for its type
>
> [*Example:* If an object x of type std::vector is in a valid but
>   unspecified state, x.empty() can be called unconditionally, and
>   x.front() can be called only if x.empty() returns false. *—end example*]

Reading the C++ standard, the state of `data()` is not specified when the vector is empty. So, the state is *valid but unspecified state*. Therefore, the returned value of `data()` when the vector is empty can be anything (null or a random value). It depends on implementation of the compiler.

In this case, following the example in §17.3, you should call `empty()` before using `data()` to ensure that the returned value is as your expectation.

```
if (!v.empty())
   do_something(v.data())
```

Comment: The state of the object here is specified - it's empty.

Comment: @Barry: _The state_ is not a random linguistic definition and you arbitrary use it. Here there is specific definition for _state_ and you should refer to the documentation for it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible, and libstdc++ is doing this.
You can have a look at the documentation of [data() in libstdc++](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/libstdc++/api/a01523_source.html#l00890)

```
 data() _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
 { return _M_data_ptr(this->_M_impl._M_start); }
```

However, performing actions on this pointer may not be specified, as you are accessing an non-initialized range within your vector, without its knowledge (e.g you don't know the exact size of the memory bunch). Also, as `size()` is 0, your valid range is still empty.

Comment: That libstdc++ does it, does not automatically imply that it is allowed according to the spec.