# Visual C++ for Python cannot handle c++11 error C2039: 'data': is not a member of std::vector

Tags: python, c++, c++11, visual-c++

Running into a compilation error using python setup.py install, and the error is the following:

```
 : error C2039: 'data' : is not a member of 'std::vector<_Ty>'
        with
        [
            _Ty=unsigned int
        ]
```

Microsoft Visual has a VC++ for Python, which uses Visual C++ 2008, which doesn't support c++11 (which I think is required for that part of the code to work.

```
std::vector<unsigned> tab((m + 1) * 2);
unsigned *cur = tab.data(), *prev = tab.data() + m + 1;
```

Is there any workaround to either that part of the code, or by forcing python install to use MV C++ 2015.

The entire code is here: https://github.com/semanticize/leven/blob/master/leven/levenshtein_impl.h

Comment: I think using C++ 11 for Python 2.7 is still a valid question because there are other error for other libraries that occur

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::vector` is guaranteed to store its data contiguously, so you can just take the address of its first element:

```
unsigned *cur = &tab[0], *prev = &tab[0] + m + 1;
```

Or perhaps it would be clearer like so:

```
unsigned *cur = &tab[0];
unsigned *prev = cur + m + 1;
```

Comment: That did it! I was able to finally build the package, and import it! 
And.. you both answered at the same time. IDK which one to mark as solution :/

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `vector::data()`, you can use:

```
&tab[0] // or &tab.front()
```

to get pointer to your vectors data. So your code would look as follows:

```
std::vector<unsigned> tab((m + 1) * 2);
unsigned *cur = &tab[0], *prev = &tab[0] + m + 1;
```

One problem with `&tab[0]` is that if tab is empty then this will result in Undefined Behaviour, at least under Visual Studio it crashes. Calling data() on empty vector gives me nullptr under VS2015. According to [What should std::vector::data() return if the vector is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25419851/what-should-stdvectordata-return-if-the-vector-is-empty) this should be unspecified behaviour. In your code vector looks like it should never be empty in that place, but to be sure you can use following code to be sure:

```
unsigned *cur = (tab.empty() ? NULL : &tab[0]), *prev = (tab.empty() ? NULL : &tab[0]) + m + 1;
```