# What does vec.data() return if vec.size() == 0?

Tags: c++, vector

[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) has this note for `std::vector::data`:

> Returns pointer to the underlying array serving as element storage. The pointer is such that range `[data(); data() + size())` **is always a valid range, even if the container is empty.**

What does "valid range" mean here exactly?  What will `data()` return if the vector is zero-length?

Specifically, for a zero-length vector:

1. Can `data()` ever be a null pointer?
2. Can it be safely dereferenced? (Even if it points to junk.)
3. Is it guaranteed to be different between two different (zero-length) vectors?

I am working with a C library that takes arrays and won't allow a null pointer even for a zero-length array.  However, it does not actually dereference the array storage pointer if the array length is zero, it just checks whether it is `NULL`.  I want to make sure that I can safely pass `data()` to this C library, so the only relevant question is (1) above.  (2) and (3) are just out of curiosity in case a similar situation comes up.

---

**Update**

Based on comments that were not turned into answers, we can try the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> v;
    cout << v.data() << endl;

    v.push_back(1);
    cout << v.data() << endl;

    v.pop_back();
    cout << v.data() << endl;

    v.shrink_to_fit();
    cout << v.data() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

With my compiler it output:

```
0x0
0x7f896b403300
0x7f896b403300
0x0
```

This shows that:

- `data()` can indeed be a null pointer, thus the answers are (1) yes (2) no (3) no
- but it is not *always* a null pointer for a zero-size vector

Yes, obviously I should have tried this before asking.

Comment: When `size() == 0`, there are no elements in `[data(); data() + size())`, so it mean there may be no valid pointer. (I post this as comment because I'm not sure)

Comment: Yes and no and no.. Don't have links to the standard right now, otherwise would have answered.

Comment: I would say that return value is undefined by being not explicitely defined by standard (`array` `data` method return value is defined to be unspecified and `begin() == end() == data()`, for example)

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot If it's undefined, it's a defect.

Comment: I said "yes" to the first point, so it can indeed be a null pointer. A null pointer plus zero (the size of an empty container) is still a null pointer. And your question 1 and 3 are kind of contradictionary, if the pointer is allowed to be a null pointer, then there can't be a guarantee that two pointers will be different.

Comment: It definitely can be null in that case. `[null, null)` is a valid range.

Comment: I think it is *defining* a "valid range" to include when `size()` returns zero so that the beginning and end pointers are the same location - *even if that location is not dereferencable*.

Comment: @Galik No, "valid range"'s defined [elsewhere](http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.requirements#iterator.requirements.general-8).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Sorry, I misread you comment.  The questions are not contradictory, it's just that a certain answer to the first one might automatically answer the rest as well.  If it's always a null pointer, then of course (3) is "no".  If it's not a null pointer then the answer to (3) might be either yes or no.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks for the link!  That could go in an answer ...  It's a bit strange that it's phrased this way though as it would seem obvious that `data() + 0` is reachable from `data()` (according to the definition in your link).

Comment: @Szabolcs: in effect all that the text "even if the container is empty" achieves in your quote, is to confirm that `data()` must return a value of type `T*` even if the vector is empty. I guess they felt the need to reinforce the point, just in case an implementer reading the text thinks that since there is no "underlying storage" for an empty vector then users aren't supposed to call `data()` on it. So, since for any pointer value `p`, `p + 0 == p` and `[p,p)` is a valid range, by saying "even when empty" they're basically just saying, "it's still a pointer".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should std::vector::data() return if the vector is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25419851/what-should-stdvectordata-return-if-the-vector-is-empty)

Comment: Yet another C++ booby trap.  I got caught just now.  Of course data() should have a defined behaviour, one way or the other.  Nasty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Too long for a comment so posting here.

I expected the iterators to be nullptr for an empty sequence so I tested it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void pr(std::vector<int>& v){
    std::cout << &*v.begin() << ", " << &*v.end() << "\n";
} 
// technically UB, but for this experiment I don't feel too bad about it.
// Thanks @Revolver    
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::vector<int> v1;
    std::vector<int> v2;

    pr(v1);
    pr(v2);

    return 0;
}
```

And this does indeed print

```
0, 0
0, 0
```

Now for an empty container the only reasonable operation for a valid range is `begin() == end()`. And no, junk can't be dereferenced so *v.begin() is not a concern.

Comment: This code contains undefined behaviour (dereferencing invalid iterators). Anyway: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ebaf9f496bbfb21

Comment: I feel embarrassed now ... of course I should have tried printing `data()`, then I would have seen that it is `0` with my compiler, which automatically answers all three questions.  It can be null, therefore there's no guarantee of difference and it can't be dereferenced.

Comment: @Szabolcs Another counterargument closer to original answer: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2ce8a1a2eeeed071  You will get null pointer only if vector __always__ was empty

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot Thanks for showing that!  `shrink_to_fit()` makes it a null pointer again with my compiler.  It would be nice to have all this written out in an answer.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question what will the vector do. It answers what your compiler did in this particular instance.

Comment: @Barry I would agree with that sentiment. That is why I prefixed it. I still found it a worthwile addition to the answers.

Comment: @Szabolcs compilers often contain bugs or don't comply to the standard, so it is still a good question even if you tested it on a compiler first

Answer (score 22):

"valid range" is defined by [iterator.requirements.general]/7 (C++14):

> "Range `[i,j)` is valid if and only if `j` is reachable from `i`".

Luckily C++ defines that adding `0` to a null pointer yields a null pointer. So, is a null pointer *reachable* from a null pointer ?  This is defined  by point 6 of the same section:

> An iterator `j` is called *reachable* from an iterator `i` if and only if there is a finite sequence of applications of the expression `++i` that makes `i == j`.

A zero-length sequence is a finite sequence, therefore `data()` may return a null pointer.

Accordingly the answers to your questions are:

> 1. Can `data()` ever be a null pointer?

**Yes**

> 2. Can it be safely dereferenced? (Even if it points to junk.)

**No**

> 3. Is it guaranteed to be different between two different (zero-length) vectors?

**No**

Comment: I am surprised that `nullptr + 0` needs to be explicitly discussed.  Aren't pointers *always* just non-negative integers (for the purpose of arithmetic, not type conversion)?  If that is the case then `nullptr + 0 == nullptr` would be obvious.

Comment: @Szabolcs: No, pointers are not even numbers. Which is quite obvious from the fact that you can't add two pointers. As for non-negative, as they're not numbers, they can't be compared with numbers, so `ptr < 0` doesn't make sense either, and they're neither signed nor unsigned.

Comment: @Szabolcs it is undefined behaviour in C

Comment: @Szabolcs: As for "Aren't pointers always just non-negative integers" No, a member pointer is often twice as big as other pointers on virtually every system.

Comment: @Szabolcs, Pointers are not numbers in C/C++. There is a clause which forbids not only dereferencing, but even mere circulation or generation of invalid pointer values. There's a reason for that. In the past, there were proposals of CPU architectures where pointers were to be stored in dedicated registers. Loading a value into such a register would cause its associated page descriptor to be prefetched, which might cause a 'premature' segmentation fault in case the value was invalid.

Comment: @Andrey Thanks for that comment!  With that context, it makes more sense.

Answer (score 5):

From the standard:

> **23.3.6.4**  **[vector.data]**
>
> T* data() noexcept;
>
> const T* data() const noexcept;
>
> Returns: A pointer such that **[data(),data() + size()) is a valid range**. For a
>   non-empty vector, data() == &front().

So it's allowed to be null for an empty vector but not necessarily dereferencable nor unique.

Comment: What part of your quote supports the assertion that `data` is allowed to be `null` for an empty vector?

Comment: It'd be good if this answer explicitly answered OP questions 1,2,3