# c++ 11: &v[0] on empty std::vector v

Tags: c++, pointers

If I have an std::vector v that can sometimes be empty, is it just pure luck with g++ that I can get the pointer to this not-existing data with &v[0] or will I get a seg fault with other compilers (my g++ is fine with the below and has never given a seg fault on actual runs for that).

```
std::vector<int> v = {}; std::cout << (&v[0] == NULL) << std::endl; // true with my g++
```

Thanks

Comment: Please check out what `v[0]` does and what the requirements are. You will find that it invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: I understand v[0] is problematic but I am wondering if it still is when used with & since the memory at v[0] is not accessed

Comment: Why don't you use `.data()` instead? Don't use `[0]` when vector is empty. Although, `data()`  and subsequently `&v[0]` may not necessarily be `0` when the vector is empty.

Comment: @Halbux `v[0]` is undefined if `v` is empty. Whether memory is physically accessed or not is irrelevant.

Comment: @molbdnilo I understand that, but clearly g++ is smart enough to see it as an atomic &v[0] and not first v[0] then &

Comment: `&v[0]` is not necessarily null when vector is empty. Even if you ignore any undefined behaviour issues.

Comment: @Halbux No, it's undefined in g++ as well, and only works through bad luck. It is impossible to determine the absence of undefined behaviour through observation. Appearing to work as intended is the most devious form of undefined behaviour.

Comment: You know that `v.empty()` does the same thing and is easier to read/just as fast, right? What are you trying to do?

Comment: If you want to explain what will actually happen when the behavior is undefined, you may check the generated assembly. Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/3azTjd. Here, the behavior is defined by the implementation (`f` returns whatever is stored in vector's [first pointer-to-data member variable](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_vector.h#L93)). Of course, this behavior is still undefined by the C++ Standard.

Comment: @ALX23z That's a good question, I will do :) Seems like the way to go, Thanks

Comment: @Halbux In that case, this is related: [What should std::vector::data() return if the vector is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25419851/580083)

Answer (score 2):

Yes your code has undefined behaviour.

`v[0]` calls a function which returns `int&`, and there are no "null references", so `&v[0]` can never be NULL in the first place. This is why clang with optimisations makes your code print `0`, and optimises the following to `return false;`:

```cpp
bool is_pointer_to_first_null(std::vector<int>& v) {
    return &v[0] == nullptr;
}
```

(Which clang also warns you of)

It also breaks the contract for `std::vector<T>::operator[](n)`, which is defined as equivalent to `*(v.begin() + n)`, and since `v.begin() + 0 == v.begin() == v.end()` for an empty vector, this is not a dereferenceable iterator, and your standard library implementation is allowed to do anything.
For example, with `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` defined, this prints `Error: attempt to subscript container with out-of-bounds index 0, but container only holds 0 elements.` with g++. (https://godbolt.org/z/anran5)

The fact that `&v[0] == nullptr` isn't optimised to `false` in gcc is a missed optimisation. Perhaps `&v[0]` is already optimised to `v.data()` first and the information that this is non-null is lost (or not used for whatever reason).
And without optimisations, gcc will gladly form null-references since references are implemented as pointers and `&reference` is a noop in assembly. This is true for most compilers on most architectures, so this is unlikely to segfault.

---

Perhaps you are looking for `v.empty()` (which could still have a non-null data pointer), `v.data() == nullptr` (When defined, `v.data() == &v[0]`), or `v.capacity() == 0`? There shouldn't be a good reason to check if the data pointer is null though.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. I will go for .data(). What I was doing is passing &v[0] to e.g. MPI_Send(&v[0], length) since it requires an int* for integers. In any case if the vector is empty MPI knows the length is 0 and does not touch the pointer at all,... so I do not care what's the pointer if the vector is empty but I care not to have a seg fault.