# Does C++ standard guarantee that std::vector's underlying pointer initialized as nullptr

Tags: c++, stdvector

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data, the underlying pointer is not guaranteed to be nullptr if the size is 0

> If size() is 0, data() may or may not return a null pointer.

but does that apply to the default initialized std::vector with no elements? or does that simply state that if all elements of the vector are erased, the underlying pointer may not become nullptr?

Consider the following line:

```
std::vector<int> fooArr;
int* fooArrPtr = fooArr.data();
```

is it guaranteed that `fooArrPtr` is equal to nullptr?

Comment: it sounds like its up to the implementation

Comment: since a new vector like `fooArr`, its size is `0`.

Comment: No. It guarantees that a default-initialised `std::vector` has `size()` equal to zero, but that doesn't require that `data()` will return `nullptr`.  There is nothing preventing (or requiring) a default-constructed `vector` to have zero `.size()` and non-zero `capacity()`, in which case it would be feasible for `data()` to return a pointer to the allocated memory (which will be non-null, but dereferencing it will still have undefined behaviour since `.size()` is zero [and allocated capacity may be uninitialised]).   If you want to test if a vector has zero size, use `.size()` or `.empty()`.

Comment: @Peter You should put that in an answer.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel   Not sure it's complete.  But will see what I can do in a few minutes.

Comment: In general, the C++ standard do not specify such implementation details more than necessary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What should std::vector::data() return if the vector is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25419851/what-should-stdvectordata-return-if-the-vector-is-empty)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.

The standard guarantees that a default-initialised `std::vector` has `size()` equal to zero, but that doesn't require that `data()` will return `nullptr`.

There is nothing in the standard that prevents (and "not preventing" is not equivalent to "requiring") a default-constructed vector having zero `.size()` and non-zero `capacity()`.   In such a case, it would be feasible for `.data()` to return a pointer to the allocated memory (which will be non-null, but dereferencing it will still have undefined behaviour since `.size()` is zero [and allocated capacity is not required to be initialised]).

If you want to test if a vector has zero size, use `.size()` or `.empty()`.  Don't call `.data()` and compare the result with `nullptr`.

Comment: C++17 and later requires the default constructor of `std::vector` to be `noexcept` iff the allocator is noexcept default constructible. Since `std::allocator` is noexcept default constructible but its `allocate()` method is not `noexcept`, the default constructor of `std::vector<T, std::allocator<T>>` can't really allocate anything, since an exception thrown by the allocator would result in `std::terminate` begin called.

Answer (score 1):

When an empty vector is instantiated, no memory is allocated.
Then clearing all the elements doesn't mean that the vector release its internal memory (this remains available when new elements will be inserted). The memory will be released only when the destructor is called.

To make a long story short, you cannot use `data()` to check if a vector is empty.

Furthermore, it is not even advisable to check if a vector has had some members in its existance depending if `data()` returns you a `nullptr` or less. You cannot be sure that the internal template implementation always grants you this property.

Comment: `no memory is allocated` I don't think this is correct, there is nothing in the standard to prevent a default constructed vector having non-zero capacity